# Negating a Task<bool> without await?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

Is there a way to negate a function that returns `Task<bool>` without explicitly running it using async/await? I have several unique checks in my FluentValidators. I wanted to do something like this:

```
public Task<bool> HasUniqueNameAsync(Entity entity, string propName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return _dbContext.Entities.AnyAsync(x => !(x.PropName == propName && x.Id != entity.Id));
}
```

However, instead of negating the boolean value, the LINQ query gets translated to

```
x.PropName != propName && x.Id == entity.Id
```

Which is not equivalent. For the time being, I've updated my unique check functions so that they look like this:

```
public async Task<bool> HasUniqueNameAsync(Entity entity, string propName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return !await _dbContext.Entities.AnyAsync(x => x.PropName == propName && x.Id != entity.Id);
}
```

Is there a way to add a negation without explicitly using async/await?

Comment: `!Any(x) == All(!x)`, `Any(!x) != !Any(x)`. And note that databases complicate matters by throwing in `null`, so that these dual transformations aren't always even possible, and there's only one "right" way to write the query.

Comment: Is [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) an option?

Comment: Just a side note: don't use `ContinueWith`. It's just a more complex and more error-prone version of `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a logical way to do this. You're currently checking "if any match" and negating it - logically, "not any match" is the same thing as "all not match". So, if your current code is:

```
public async Task<bool> HasUniqueNameAsync(Entity entity, string propName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return !await _dbContext.Entities.AnyAsync(x => x.PropName == propName && x.Id != entity.Id);
}
```

then you can move the negation into the function by doing this:

```
public Task<bool> HasUniqueNameAsync(Entity entity, string propName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return _dbContext.Entities.AllAsync(x => !(x.PropName == propName && x.Id != entity.Id));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use continuations to tack operations onto a task to be executed when it finishes:

```
public async Task<bool> HasUniqueNameAsync(Entity entity, string propName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return !await _dbContext.Entities
        .AnyAsync(x => x.PropName == propName && x.Id != entity.Id)
        .ContinueWith(x => !x.Result);
}
```

Finally, I note that you're not using that `CancellationToken` in your code. You should pass that into `AnyAsync()` (and also into `ContinueWith()` if you choose to go that route).

Comment: Had never thought to use the AllAsync() function. Seems to fit the bill; allows me to avoid async/await without any other workarounds. Will have to inspect the SQL to see what is under the hood and do some performance testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could return a [continuation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netcore-3.0) negating the result from the `AnyAsync` task:

```
public Task<bool> HasUniqueNameAsync(Entity entity, string propName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    return _dbContext.Entities
        .AnyAsync(x => x.PropName == propName && x.Id != entity.Id))
        .ContinueWith(continuation => !continuation.Result, cancellationToken );
}
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it.